# How are "Active Installs" counted on plugin page?

Tags: plugins

What constitutes an active install in the counter displayed on the Plugin Store? in other words, what does the "active" adjective designate in this context? Is there an "inactive" install?

[image: Active Installs Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Active" is how many times that plugin has been installed on a Craft site within the last year.